# Set up websockets with Jetty 11

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I am trying to migrate from Jetty 9.4 to Jetty 11 (maybe too early?) and failing in adapting the code for setting up websockets. The way I achieved this in 9.4 was as follows:

```
Server server = new Server();
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setSendServerVersion(false);
HttpConnectionFactory httpFactory = new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig);
ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(server, httpFactory);
httpConnector.setPort(port);
server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { httpConnector });

// Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
// This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");

// Add a websocket to a specific path spec
ServletHolder holderEvents2 = new ServletHolder("websocket", EventsServlet.class);
context.addServlet(holderEvents2, "/events/*");

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { context, new DefaultHandler() });

server.setHandler(handlers);

public class EventsServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        // register a socket class as default
        factory.register(EchoSocket.class);
    }
}

public class EchoSocket implements WebSocketListener {
    // ...
}
```

As there is no WebSocketServlet class anymore, I fiddled around a bit and found the class JettyWebSocketServlet. According to its JavaDoc, I thought it should like as follows:

```
public class EventsServlet extends JettyWebSocketServlet {

    @Override
    protected void configure(JettyWebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        // register a socket class as default
//      factory.register(EchoSocket.class);
           factory.addMapping("/", (req,res)->new EchoSocket());

    }
}
```

but the line with addMapping is actually never executed. Also JettyWebSocketServletFactory does not have a method called setDefaultMaxFrameSize as suggested by the JavaDoc of JettyWebSocketServlet .

All I seem to be able to find on the web is for Jetty <= 9.4, even https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples .

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem, though my version running under Jetty 9.4 was a bit different to yours, using `WebSocketHandler` rather than `WebSocketServlet`. I was having some problems with the old approach, since under Jetty 9.4 I had to pass my listener class as a `Class` object, which makes dependency injection a pain.

I have now got this working under Jetty 11.0.0 though. I found your question a couple of days ago while I was trying to work out how to do this in Jetty 11, and it inspired me to actually get this working, so thanks!

FWIW, my Jetty 9.4 version (for a trivial test) looked like this:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{
    int serverPort = Integer.getInteger("server.port", 8080);

    Server server = new Server(serverPort);
    ContextHandlerCollection handlers = new ContextHandlerCollection();

    WebSocketHandler wsh = new WebSocketHandler.Simple (TestWebSocketListener.class);
    handlers.addHandler(createContextHandler("/ws", wsh));

    ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();
    rh.setDirectoriesListed(false);
    rh.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("/WEB-STATIC/"));
    handlers.addHandler(createContextHandler("/", rh));

    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}

// Convenience method to create and configure a ContextHandler.
private static ContextHandler createContextHandler(String contextPath, Handler wrappedHandler)
{
    ContextHandler ch = new ContextHandler (contextPath);
    ch.setHandler(wrappedHandler);
    ch.clearAliasChecks();
    ch.setAllowNullPathInfo(true);
    return ch;
}
```

Here, `TestWebSocketListener` is a trivial implementation of `WebSocketListener` which just implements each listener method and prints the arguments to `System.err`. (I did say this was a trivial test.) I also send a message back to the client in the `onWebSocketText` callback, just to check that this works.

I'm not using `DefaultHandler` here - instead, I explicitly create a `ResourceHandler` which serves a few simple static resources from a resource tree stored within the classpath (under the `/WEB-STATIC/` prefix).

The version I have working under Jetty 11.0.0 just changes the `main` method above to this:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception
{
    int serverPort = Integer.getInteger("server.port", 8080);

    Server server = new Server(serverPort);
    ContextHandlerCollection handlers = new ContextHandlerCollection();

    ResourceHandler rh = new ResourceHandler();
    rh.setDirectoriesListed(false);
    rh.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("/WEB-STATIC/"));
    handlers.addHandler(createContextHandler("/", rh));

    Servlet websocketServlet = new JettyWebSocketServlet() {
        @Override protected void configure(JettyWebSocketServletFactory factory) {
            factory.addMapping("/", (req, res) -> new TestWebSocketListener());
        }
    };
    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
    servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(websocketServlet), "/ws");
    JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(servletContextHandler, null);
    handlers.addHandler(servletContextHandler);

    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

The call to `JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure` is important: without that I got exceptions complaining that the WebSocket components had not been initialised.

One thing to note is that the order of the two handlers has been changed - previously, the `WebSocketHandler` was added before the `ResourceHandler`. However, when using `ServletContextHandler` this was returning 404s for paths that should have been handled by the `ResourceHandler`, so I swapped the order.

The `TestWebSocketListener` is identical between the two versions. Obviously, it's a lot easier for me to add dependency injection now I control the constructor call!

The other thing I had to change was the names of the Maven artifacts I pulled in. The `websocket-server` artifact no longer seems to exist in Jetty 11, so I changed this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.35.v20201120</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.35.v20201120</version>
</dependency>
```

to this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed & helpful answer which helped me to solve my problem. I will add the final solution for my code as another answer.

Comment: For those who need TestWebSocketListener :

class TestWebSocketListener implements WebSocketListener {
    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(java.lang.String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

Comment: the line 
 -> JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(servletContextHandler, null);

made the difference. I was getting an error Websocket components not initialized error without this.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the detailed explanation by mdf, I was able to fix my code. In the end, I only had to replace

```
ServletHolder holderEvents = new ServletHolder("websocket", EventsServlet.class);
context.addServlet(holderEvents, "/events/*");
```

with

```
Servlet websocketServlet = new JettyWebSocketServlet() {
    @Override
    protected void configure(JettyWebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.addMapping("/", (req, res) -> new EchoSocket());
    }
};
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(websocketServlet), "/events/*");
JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(context, null);
```

With this I could also get rid of the EventsServlet class.

Answer (score 2):

You can find info in the Jetty 11 examples https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/11.0.x/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventServer.java

Upgraded from jetty 9 with the following packages

1. `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:11.0.0`
2. `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:11.0.0`
3. `org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:11.0.0`
4. `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-jetty-server:11.0.0`
5. `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-jetty-client:11.0.0`

Notice that the names of the `websocket-client` and `websocket-server` changed to `websocket-jetty-client` and `websocket-jetty-server`

as pointed by @mdf `JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure` enables to get rid of the following message:

> WebSocketComponents has not been created

Now my app works with jetty 11.

this is my WebsocketServlet

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.JettyWebSocketServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.JettyWebSocketServletFactory;

public class KernelServlet extends JettyWebSocketServlet {
    @Override
    public void configure(JettyWebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.register(KernelHandler.class);
    }
}
```

and this is the server init code

```
Server server = new Server(port);
ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
contextHandler.addServlet(WebClientServlet.class, "/client");
contextHandler.addServlet(KernelServlet.class, "/kernel");
JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(contextHandler, null);
try {
    server.setHandler(contextHandler);
    server.start();
    server.join();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```